# Как удалить записи в двух таблицах по общему условию SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня есть 2 таблицы. `Days` и `Parameters`. В первой таблицe - `id`, `days`(int). Во второй таблице - `id`, `param`(int), `daysId`(int). `daysId` - ключ из первой таблицы. Необходимо удалить данные из первой таблицы, где `days` < 90, но и также необходимо удалить из второй таблицы параметры, которые привязаны к удаляемым данным по `daysId`. Как это можно связать 2 таблицы в запросе `delete`?

В моих таблицах больше столбцов, я привел минимальный пример.

Comment: А СУБД у вас какая?

Comment: @Viktorov MS Server

Comment: Я не работал с СКЛ сервером. Мне кажется, можно  настроить FK с удалением каскадом, и тогда удалять надо будет в принципе только из 1 таблицы

Comment: Или можно написать 2 запроса, и все

Comment: *`daysId` - ключ из первой таблицы* FK имеется? Создайте и установите ON DELETE CASCADE - оно само удалится...

Comment: А, вспомнил универ) понял, надо настроить получается просто, чтобы это было не просто число, а FK и всё. Спасибо большое)

Comment: А я так делать не рекомендую, лучше двумя запросами ибо это логика, она должна стоиться только на ХП и запросах. Наличие таких вещей надо тщательно документировать, это небезопасное решение.

Comment: @NickProskuryakov а в чем заключается опасность решения?

Comment: @Viktorov только лишь в том, что удаляя данные из одной таблицы вы удалите и данные из другой, этого вплоне достаточно)

Comment: @NickProskuryakov а зачем нужны данные, которые ни с чем нельзя связать? Это как раз те данные, которые после удаления данных из первой таблицы не представляют никакой ценности. Более того, они являются мусором.

Comment: @Viktorov я уже вижу ваши галаза, когда ваш джун не зная о каскаде, удаляет одну запись из таблицы, а у вас каскадом тянется несколько тысяч из другой. На проде так делать нельзя.

Comment: @NickProskuryakov я сейчас по ошибке, удалил значения вместе больше 90, меньше 90, в итоге небольшая работа за неделю стерлась :D

Comment: @NickProskuryakov на мой взгляд, такие вещи должны решаться архитектурой. Если данные имеют ценность без мастер таблицы, то запретить удаление каскадом. А если при удалении из основной таблицы, они должны удаляться так же, то каскадное удаление в самый раз. СУБД специально созданы, для того чтобы работать с данными. Почему бы не использовать их для этого? (это риторический вопрос).
Ваш подход я понял, просто не согласен. Хорошего дня =)

Comment: @Viktorov спасибо и вам)

Answer (score 0):

Для каскадного удаления: предварительно установите параметер `ON DELETE CASCADE`

```
DELETE FROM Days 
WHERE days < 90;
```

Удаления двумя запросами:

`DELETE FROM Days d 
  WHERE d.days < 90;
  DELETE FROM Parameters p
  WHERE p.daysId IN (
  SELECT * FROM Days d 
  WHERE d.days < 90);`

Comment: @Nick Proskuryakov, я знаю, я четко разделил где какое удаление!